# Image transformation in OpenCV does not match point transformation

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am distorting an image using `ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer` from OpenCV 3.4.2 in C++. Separately, using the same object, I want to distort 3 points from the initial image in the destination image. To visualize the transformation I use 3 triangles:

1. green: the triangle drawn on the original image. This one will be
   distorted with the image.
2. blue: the reference triangle (initial coordinates)
3. red: the triangle after the distorting the points

Original image:
[image: original image]

Original image augmented with a triangle for reference:
[image: original image]

Distorted image + separate point transformation, red triangle should overlap the green one. Blue is the initial one.
[image: distorted image]

Code:

```
void transform()
{
    Mat img = imread("test.jpg"); // the posted original image
    auto tps = cv::createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer();
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> sourcePoints, targetPoints, myPoints;
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(100, 0));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(650, 40));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(500, 0));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 599));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 450));
    sourcePoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(799, 599));
    targetPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(600, 599));

    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sourcePoints.size(); i++)
        matches.push_back(cv::DMatch(i, i, 0));

    tps->estimateTransformation(sourcePoints, targetPoints, matches);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> transPoints, transPoints2;

    //======== draw test points
    myPoints.push_back(Point2f(100, 100));
    myPoints.push_back(Point2f(200, 200));
    myPoints.push_back(Point2f(100, 400));
    line(img, myPoints[0], myPoints[1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    line(img, myPoints[1], myPoints[2], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    line(img, myPoints[2], myPoints[0], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);

    //========= warp image
    Mat img2 = img.clone();
    tps->warpImage(img, img2);

    //========= warp points
    tps->applyTransformation(myPoints, transPoints);
    //tps->applyTransformation(transPoints2, transPoints);
    line(img2, transPoints[0], transPoints[1], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
    line(img2, transPoints[1], transPoints[2], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
    line(img2, transPoints[2], transPoints[0], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);

    //========== draw reference points
    line(img2, myPoints[0], myPoints[1], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
    line(img2, myPoints[1], myPoints[2], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
    line(img2, myPoints[2], myPoints[0], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

    imshow("img", img);
    imshow("img2", img2);

    get_test_contur();
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I don't understand why the result (red triangle) doesn't overlap the green triangle. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like `applyTransformation` applies the mapping in reverse from what `warpImage` does?

Comment: @CrisLuengo it does seem that way from the pictures, but the documentation does not appear to say that?

Comment: It could be a bug. I stared at your code for a while, I can't see anything weird in it.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative using OpenCV?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. You could look through the source code to see if you can spot the issue.